# How to do an array field match in mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have a collection of documents with a field like: `subjects: ['science', 'math', 'english']`, I have another array like `subjects_two: ['science', 'biology', 'economics']`, how do I filter the collection so that all documents with at least one element in `subjects_two` array is in the `subjects` field of the document?

Comment: Using `$in` operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: @DheemanthBhat thank you, but how would I sort the documents based on the amount of elements that match?

Comment: Post some documents with expected data. Also what you have tried so far. It helps thanks.